# Wordpress and the_content()

Tags: wordpress

Anyone knows why the_content() doesn't show on my single.php page, while it shows up on index.php?

```
<div class="block">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p class="date">
        <?php the_date('d F Y'); ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you may need to upload the code from single.php and index.php somewhere using pastebin.com, maybe. So that we can see what goes wrong...

Comment: is the title showing and the date correct ? is it within the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your single.php page nad index page `the_*()` functions are only designed to be used within  the loop.

```
while(have_posts())
{
   ///the_content(); the_title(); the_post(); etc
}

//If I Used here then it would not work!
```

Comment: try change the_content to the_post()

Comment: how on earth is the title and date showing, if there is no loop to call them?

Comment: @danixd you can still use some of the "the_*()" functions outputting content because there also used on pages as well as posts. the_title for example outside the loop in index.php will return the title for the latest topic....